# Is there a way to delete multiple Picasa Web Albums in one operation?

Tags: picasa-web-albums

I have a bunch of albums that I need to delete from Picasaweb.  Is there a way to do this, or do I have to go through them one at a time to delete them?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use the [Google Command Line tool](http://code.google.com/p/googlecl/).

```
google picasa list  
google picasa delete --title "Your album name"
```

You would have to create a batch file to delete multiple albums by name.

Or try typing in part of an album name as a wildcard. Experiment with it. It will prompt you with [a confirmation on every album](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aR9BI.png) that matches the wildcard as seen below:

```
yes | google picasa delete --title "2010."
HINT: No need to include "google" in interactive mode
Are you SURE you want to delete album "2010.8.09"? (y/N): y
Are you SURE you want to delete album "2010.08.09"? (y/N): y
Are you SURE you want to delete album "2010.08.14"? (y/N): y
Are you SURE you want to delete album "2010.07.29"? (y/N): y
Are you SURE you want to delete album "2010.06.09"? (y/N): y
```

Comment: Thanks for this. For some reason the `google picasa list` command never returns for me. But the deleting worked. Also It crashed on the first album (Auto Backup) if I selected all albums ".*", but otherwise this saved me hours for deleting thousands of albums.

Comment: This could've been the greatest answer ever if only Google Command Line Tool  still worked: as of October 2015, since OAuth1 doesn't seem to be supported any longer by Google, these command line tools don't work any more. From the link provided in the answer: ```8 June 2015: GoogleCL is currently broken due to the OAuth1 turndown, and likely to remain so. Thanks for your support over the years, and apologies for the lack of prior notice.```

Answer (score 2):

This Linux shell script will delete all albums from your Picasa account. It uses `curl` in combination with the Google Picasa Web-API.
Just change the username and password regarding your account in the script.

```
#!/bin/sh

# Tutorial: https://developers.google.com/gdata/articles/using_cURL
# Requires: curl, grep, sed

ACCOUNT="GOOGLE"
USERNAME="user@gmail.com"
PASSWORD="pass"
SERVICE="lh2"

# authenticate
AUTH_KEY=$(curl --silent "https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin?accountType=$ACCOUNT&Email=$USERNAME&Passwd=$PASSWORD&service=$SERVICE" | grep 'Auth=' | sed -e 's|Auth=||g')
AUTH_HEADER="Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=$AUTH_KEY"

# get album list for deletion
RESPONSE=$(curl --silent --header "$AUTH_HEADER" "http://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/default")
ALBUM_LIST_EDIT=$(echo "$RESPONSE" | sed -e 's|<link rel=.edit. type=.application/atom+xml. href=.|\n|g;s|./><link|\n|g' | grep '^http://')

# delete all albums
for ALBUM in $ALBUM_LIST_EDIT
do
    echo "$ALBUM" | sed 's|.*api|\.|g'
    curl --request DELETE --header "$AUTH_HEADER" "$ALBUM"
done
```

Comment: This was a good idea but it no longer works, so don't bother. When I attempt to perform the first request manually I am instructed to go to https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/AuthForInstalledApps, which in turn says this: ```Important: ClientLogin has been officially deprecated since April 20, 2012 and is now no longer available. Requests to ClientLogin will fail with a HTTP 404 response. We encourage you to migrate to OAuth 2.0 as soon as possible.```

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't appear to be a way to delete multiple albums from the web interface. You'll need to do them one at a time. (It makes sense, really. Imagine the mess you would make if you deleted whole swaths of your albums at once in error.)

Comment: Sorry... In Picasa 3, the feature to delete empty web albums is found at Tools | Experimental | Delete Empty Web Albums (http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/picasa/picasa-web-albums/jmygIn-iywc). I have used this feature many times.

Answer (score 0):

*(originally from [a comment](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2743/is-there-a-way-to-delete-multiple-picasa-web-albums-in-one-operation#comment20833_2755) by [Shannon Wagner](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/17203/shannon-wagner))*

In Picasa 3, the feature to delete empty web albums is found at `Tools | Experimental | Delete Empty Web Albums`. ([source](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/picasa/picasa-web-albums/jmygIn-iywc))

I have used this feature many times.

Comment: Does this still work now that Picasa Web Albums has been almost entirely replaced by Google Photos?

Answer (score -1):

You can remove multiple PWA online albums from within the Picasa application:
http://support.google.com/picasa/answer/187407

*Tools* → *Batch Upload* → *Remove Online* → Simply select the albums you'd like to remove and click OK.

Comment: I'm receiving a message saying that "photos can't be deleted from Google+" when trying this.